# Issue with table and text width

Tags: tables, width

I ask for help since I cannot cope with an issue occurring in the compilation of my LaTeX file. I put a table in a section (documentclass `cv`), but unfortunately the table starts from the middle of the text; I would like to fit the table to the width of the page.

P.S. I have already tried centering, but it does not work.

If you would have some advice or tips, I would be very grateful.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{cv}

\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\Language{francais}

\definecolor{urlcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}

\geometry{
hmargin=1cm,            
vmargin=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{section}{Formation}

\begin{tabular}{lll} 
2013-201 & x & Master Finance d'Entreprise et Pratique des March\'{e}s Financiers \\[1mm]

2012-2014 & x & Dipl\^{o}me d'Institut d'\'{e}tudes politiques \\[1mm]

2011-2012 & x & School of Economics \& University of Edinburgh Business School \\[1mm]

2010-2012 & x & Bachelor\'{}s degree in Business Administration \\[1mm]

2008-2010 & x & Classe pr\'{e}paratoire aux grandes \'{e}coles, Kh\^{a}gne, Mention Tr\`{e}s bien \\[1mm] 

2008 & x & Baccalaur\'{e}at en sciences \'{e}conomiques et sociales, Mention Bien \\[1mm] 

\end{tabular}
\end{section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the class file `cv`? By the way welcome to TeX.SX.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the tabularx package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  top=0.75in,            
  inner=0.25in,
  outer=0.25in,
  bottom=0.75in,      
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
        \hline
    2013-201 & x & Master Finance d'Entreprise et Pratique des March\'{e}s Financiers \\[1mm]

    2012-2014 & x & Dipl\^{o}me d'Institut d'\'{e}tudes politiques \\[1mm]

    2011-2012 & x & School of Economics \& University of Edinburgh Business School \\[1mm]

    2010-2012 & x & Bachelor\'{}s degree in Business Administration \\[1mm]

    2008-2010 & x & Classe pr\'{e}paratoire aux grandes \'{e}coles, Kh\^{a}gne, Mention Tr\`{e}s bien \\[1mm] 

    2008 & x & Baccalaur\'{e}at en sciences \'{e}conomiques et sociales, Mention Bien \\[1mm] 
    \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]